# I demand that I be available. What does this sentence mean?

Tags: interpretation

> I demand that I be available.

I think 'demand' is used when someone demands that other person do something.
But in this sentence, I demand to myself. It's weired.

What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally demand something *of* or *from* yourself (not *to* yourself - that's not grammatically correct). Just as you can boss someone else around with demands, you can boss your future self around.

Here's a short story for some context:

CONTEXT #1

Let's say you have a friend in town, someone you rarely see. Maybe this friend has asked you on several occasions to get food together, but you're always "too busy", and neither of you can make your schedules line up. Finally, it's the last day your friend is in town. Friend wants to meet up with you for lunch before s/he departs for the airport. It's your last chance to see your friend. "Can we get lunch before I leave?" says your friend. You say, "I have a busy day, but it's the last chance we'll have, so I will make myself available. I *demand* that I be available!"

In this context, you're demanding that you yourself clear up your schedule to be available for lunch with your friend. No excuses. It's a self-demand.

CONTEXT #2

In another context, let's say you have some meeting that prevents you from having lunch with your friend. You can't simply not go without informing the other attendees. So you go to your boss and ask, "Can I be excused from this meeting?" Your boss says no. You shout, "I demand that I be available!"

Here, you're saying to the boss: I demand *of you* that *you*, the person of whom I'm making this demand, rearrange my schedule so that I will be available to make this lunch date with my friend.

So in this context, you're actually demanding something from someone else, the boss.

Comment: Thx. lunch date is a noun?(date is a noun here?)

Comment: Yup! A "lunch date" with a friend is like a casual meeting with the friend that occurs over lunch.

Answer (score -2):

It is a strange sentence.  If I saw that sentence, I would assume that the author made a typo and meant to say, "I demand that you be available."